# Automated End to End Testing for Office Add-in

Tags: ms-office

Is there a recommended way ( packages, frameworks, etc) to setup automated end to end testing for office add-ins. All my searches for testing resulted in side loading the app and manual testing.

ex: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing

Since the app needs to be loaded within an office product, current methods I use for automating tests of web applications (karma and mocha) don't work... or at least I am not sure how to set them up.

I am participating in the Hack Productivity competition and was hoping to add automated testing to my submission.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you consider tools for automated UI testing, such as Visual Studio (Ultimate) CodedUI tests, or commercial tools such as Ranorex? There is also the new WinAppDriver for Appium, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WinAppDriverTestAnyAppWithAppiumsSeleniumlikeTestsOnWindows.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk Vollmar said, it is possible to automate e2e-Tests for Office Add-ins using Appium and WinAppDriver. The HTML Elements of your app can be accessed by their id or via other methods. [This gh repo](https://github.com/phlppnhllngr/office-addin-integration-testing) contains a how-to.